# Как отменить отправку поля формы?

Tags: jquery, javascript, form

Есть форма:

```
<form id="fmask" action="" method="get">
    <input name="a1" id="a1">
    <input name="a2" id="a2">
    <input name="a3" id="a3">
    <input name="a4" id="a4">
    <input name="a5" id="a5">

    <input type="button" value="Отправить вопрос" class="submit">
</form>
```

Как отправить только a2 и a4, например. Использую jquery.

Comment: @andre777, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну как-то так:

```
$('.submit').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var $this = $(this);
   var $form = $this.closest('form');
   var _data = {
       'a2':$form.find('[name="a2"]').val(),
       'a4':$form.find('[name="a4"]').val()
   };
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: $form.attr('action'),
       data: _data,
       success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
       },
       error: function(response) {
            alert(response);
       }
   });
});
```

Ну а вообще глупость, отправляйте всё ( `$.serialize();` ), а на серваке смотрите уже, что использовать, а что нет.

Comment: С таким скриптом и форма в принципе  не нужна, можно сделать просто контейнер с полями.

Answer (score 3):

Приветствую!

Можно отлавливать событие отправки формы:

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
     $('#a3').val('');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Если форма отправляется `$.ajax`, то `data` можно сформировать одним из 2-х способов:

```
data = $("#a2, #a4").serialize();

$("#a1, #a3, #a5").prop("disabled", true);
data = $("#fmask").serialize();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#fmFullSrch').submit(function(){
    $('input[type=text]', this).each(function(i) {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).prop('disabled',true);
        }
    });
});
```

Такой код при отправке формы исключит из передачи поля без текста. Аналогично можно сделать с любым элементом формы.

Answer (score 1):

Можно извратиться, тупо поудалять остальные `$("input...").remove()`.
А как эта форма вообще сабмитится? В ней же ни `button[submit]`, ни `input[submit]` нету.

Answer (score 0):

Можно проверять на пустые значения и не отправлять их, а непустые отправлять.